# While running Swashbuckle CLI I am getting error Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: From Azure pipelines

Tags: python, .net, azure-devops, devops

I am generating DLL and with the help of DLL, I am generating Client SDK in the other stage. While running the Swashbuckle CLI I am getting this error. What might be the problem?

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /home/vsts/work/1/a/app/ABC.WebAPI.dll
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__2(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 41
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59       at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 121
```

I mentioned the Swashbuckle CLI version in `.csproj`.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline is running on agent, which has working directory like `/home/vsts/work/1`, your source code, artifact...etc should be checkout to this folder.

As per the error message, it's `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` error, and it refers to `C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\` which is NOT under working directory above.

Please check the path for the file reference, suggest to use relative path. Make sure it goes to correct path to find the reference.

In addition, there is a similar [issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1300), which indicates to upgrade Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. Please check if it helps.